# C# How to use values in array from one Class to another Class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, methods, switch-statement

I need help to complete this C# programming.

Here are what I made to prompt user for 3 code of colour and display the names of colour.

(Assume that they are supposed to input only 'A','B', or'C')

This is Class1

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

    class Class1
    {
        private char code;
        public char Code { get; set; }
        public Class1(char aCode)
        {
            code = aCode;
        }
    }
```

This is Class2

```
class Class2
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int x;
            char charCode;
            Class1[] valueCodeArray = new Class1[3];
            
            for (x = 0; x < valueCodeArray.Length; ++x)
            {
                WriteLine("Input color code No{0}",x+1);
                charCode = Convert.ToChar(ReadLine());
                valueCodeArray[x] = new Class1(charCode);
            }

            for (x = 0; x <valueCodeArray.Length ; ++x)
            {
                string NameOfCode = changeCodeToName(valueCodeArray[x].Code);
                WriteLine("No{0}: color is {1}", x + 1, NameOfCode);
            }
        }
        public static string changeCodeToName(char charCode)
        {

            string NameOfCode = "";
            switch (charCode)
            {
                case 'A':
                        NameOfCode = "Red";
                    return NameOfCode;

                case 'B':
                    NameOfCode = "Blue";
                    return NameOfCode;
                case 'C':
                    NameOfCode = "Green";
                    return NameOfCode;
            }
            return "";


        }

    }
```

The output displays... **No1: color is Red.  No2: color is Blue.  No3: color is Green**

Then I want to include this array in Class1

```
readonly string[] nameArray = new string[3] { "Red", "Blue", "Green"};
```

To use this in Class2, I have to change something in the method.

```
public static string changeCodeToName(char charCode)

    {

        string NameOfCode = "";
        switch (charCode)
        {
            case 'A':
                    NameOfCode = //nameArray[0];
                return NameOfCode;

            case 'B':
                NameOfCode = //nameArray[1];
                return NameOfCode;
            case 'C':
                NameOfCode = //nameArray[2];
                return NameOfCode;
        }
        return "";


    }
```

I changed "Red" to nameArray[0] but didn't work.

Comment: What does _”didn’t work”_ mean? Did you get an error? Some other value?

Comment: perhaps you're passing a lowercase letter instead of capital-case letter. either include the lowercase in the switch `case 'A': case 'a': return nameArray[0];` or normalize the input.

Comment: Hi @JohnG Yes when I just put  "nameArray[0]" where "Red" was, red line appeared under "nameArray[0]" .

Comment: Have you tried making `nameArray` a `static` variable? Something like… `readonly static string[] nameArray = new string[3] { "Red", "Blue", "Green" };`

Comment: @JohnG Yes I put readonly static string[] nameArray = new string[3] { "Red", "Blue", "Green" }; in Class1

Comment: If you put the definition in `Class1`... then the method `changeCodeToName` that is trying to use `nameArray` does not have access to it. It may help to make it a global variable.

Comment: @JohnG Is it possible for you to fix them by adding the global variable?

Comment: Well… since the only place in your code that uses the array `nameArray` is in the `changeCodeToName` method… then put the definition as the first line in that method.

Comment: @gon - There are no global variables in c#.

Answer (score 1):

I would encapsulate the name into your `Class1`.

```
class Class1
{
    private static Dictionary<char, string> __names = new Dictionary<char, string>()
    {
        { 'A', "Red" },
        { 'B', "Blue" },
        { 'C', "Green" },
    };
    public char Code { get; private set; }
    public string Name => __names.ContainsKey(this.Code) ? __names[this.Code] : "";
    public Class1(char code)
    {
        this.Code = code;
    }
}
```

That's really where it belongs.

Now the rest of your code becomes simple:

```
for (x = 0; x < valueCodeArray.Length; ++x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No{0}: color is {1}", x + 1, valueCodeArray[x].Name);
}
```